# hair/particles on a material

Tags: particles

[image]I have a model with a boolean modifier to make a hole, the hole has a different material inherited from the modifier. Is there a way to add particles to this material only? Since it's from a modifier it doesn't have a vertex group.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more? I think I understand what you are saying but I am not sure.

Comment: I added a picture. TLDR can I add particles only to a material. Longer read can I add particles to the edge of a material?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes. But use Vertex group for that as usual**

You need two vertex groups: one for the base mesh (should be empty), and one for the cutter (should be filled).

[image]

The tricky part is that vertex groups merged not by name, but by its index. So the first vertex group of the first mesh will be merged with the first vertex group of the second mesh, the second vertex group will be merged with the second, etc... And it doesn't matter that names your vertex groups have.

Once you get the "combined" vertex group, set it to the Density setting

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I needed. If you're ok with a side question, is there a way to make the particles more dense around the limit?

Comment: @francois If you don't mind, please ask this as a new question. We're trying to keep it one question per post here. Thanks :)

Comment: Yep, it's way more difficult than original one.  Post it separately.